# jquery select2 change option text

Tags: jquery-select2

Can I change the text of an option value?
I cant find how to do this...

I must do this

```
$("#select").select2("destroy");
$('#select option[value="' + id + '"]').text(new_text);
$("#select").select2();
```

thanks in advance !

Comment: sorry, maybe I had expressed bad.. My code is working... but i want a solution without destroying and recreating the SELECT2 component

Comment: Please read my comment in my answer below. If you think I have misunderstood your question again, please edit your question with relevant explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Struggled also with this issue. Found a cleaner way.

```js
var $select = $('.js-select2');

$select.select2({
  templateResult: updateSelectTemplate,
  templateSelection: updateSelectTemplate
})

function updateSelectTemplate(data) {
    var $option = $(data.element);

    return $option.data('display');
}

$('.js-change').on('click', function(e) {
  $select.find('option:first').data('display', 'Some new value');
  $select.trigger('change');
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-select2">
   <option data-display="Display 1"></option>
   <option data-display="Display 2"></option>
   <option data-display="Display 3"></option>
</select>

<button class="js-change">Change value</button>
```

Comment: I don't get this line, $select.find('option:first').data('display', 'Some new value'). What is the "display", is it the old data or the element/attribute?

Comment: $.data() reads / writes data attributes in html. First parameter translates to data-{name-of-param), so in this example $.data('display') references to data-display attribute in html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#select").trigger("change");
```

**Edited**
For some weird reason in your code the below thing works for me:

```
$("#select").select2("destroy");
$('#select option[value="' + id + '"]').text(new_text);
window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#select").select2();
                },0);
```

Comment: no, that will trigger a change event.. and I need to "change" a text value of an option.

Comment: sorry, maybe I had expressed bad.. My code is working... but i want a solution without destroying and recreating the SELECT2 component

Comment: You can surely update the values of <select> but to reflect the change on UI using select2, you will need to recreate or reload the object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I could not find any solution using the select2 API. My workaround was to just target the `<span>` element that is created when initialising select2.

In my case I just needed to select the first option, this is my code. With some adaptation, you can target any option you'd like.

```
$("#select").next().find( '.select2-selection__rendered:first')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var select = $("#select_id").select2();
$('#select_id').select2();
 
$('#referecedField').on('click', function() {
        select.select2('destroy');          
        $("#select_id").find("option:selected").text('New_Text');
        select.select2();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js" ></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="select_id" style="width: 200px">
<option value"1">Text 1</option>
<option value"2">Text 2</option>
<option value"3">Text 3</option>
</select>

<button id="referecedField">Change text of the selected option</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

If you change only with the name of the option

```
$('#select option:contains("Old Value")').text('New Value');
```

or if you want to change it with the id of the option

```
$('#' + yourId).text('New Value);
```

and just like other said, you must trigger the change event (to notify the select2 that data changed)

```
$("#select").trigger("change");
```